# SQL get the specific results based on date

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I have a table like this,

```
Country         | Store     | Stock | Display | Designation  | Date
--------------- | --------- | ----- | ------- | -------------| ----------
USA             | USD       | 10    | Yes     | Merchandiser | 2017-07-16 
USA             | USD       | 20    | Yes     | Merchandiser | 2017-07-16
USA             | USD       | 30    | Yes     | Promoter     | 2017-07-16
USA             | USD       | 40    | Yes     | Promoter     | 2017-07-16
```

I want to be result like this

```
Country         | Store     | Stock | Display | Designation  | Date
--------------- | --------- | ----- | ------- | -------------| ----------
USA             | USD       | 30    | Yes     | Promoter     | 2017-07-16
USA             | USD       | 40    | Yes     | Promoter     | 2017-07-16
```

Condition is date are some in both merchandiser and promoter get only promoter records only. if same date get promoter data, Dynamically check the date.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?  Your question as states is just `where designation = 'Promoter'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM table t1 
JOIN table t2 
ON t2.Designation = 'Merchandiser' 
AND t2.Date = t1.Date 
WHERE t1.Designation = 'Promoter'
```

Of course, you would need to replace `table` with the actual table name. The idea is that you do an inner join of the table to itself.

Comment: Thanks Your Comment. But i am getting repeated records

Comment: I edited my answer to add a `DISTINCT` which may possibly resolve the duplicates. If not, then you may need to specify additional JOIN criteria, if any additional JOIN criteria make sense for your requirements. Can you identify any such criteria (for example, `Country` may be one such criteria)? It really depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to understand what you're looking for.  Your condition is very hard to read.  The English doesn't make much sense, but I understand English is not your first language.

This query will return any Promoter record that has a Merchandiser record on the same date.  I think that's what you're looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t1
WHERE t1.Designation = 'Promoter'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Table t2 
        WHERE t2.Date = t1.Date
            AND t2.Designation = 'Merchandiser'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Designation='Promoter' AND Date='2017-07-16'
```

Comment: No i want dynamically

Comment: select * from table where Designation='Promoter' 
group by Date

Comment: group by only working for aggregate function not working for this query